# Proving a half-plane is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Given a half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ described by the equation $2x-3y \leq6$, how would one go about proving this vector space "$S$" is convex? Clearly it is when graphed, but I'm a bit puzzled by how to prove it.

My approach so far is to use the logic that for any vector $P$ and $Q$ in $S$, all points described by $(1-t)P+tQ$ must be in $S$, given $0\leq t\leq 1$. From here, I have got the following so far:

Let $A = (2,-3)$

Let $X = (x,y)$

$$(1-t)P+tQ = (1-t)A\cdot X_1+tA\cdot X_2$$

From here, by associative properties, the following should hold (no?):

$$(1-t)P+tQ = A\cdot (1-t)X_1+A\cdot tX_2$$

At this point, I believe I'm seeing the following:

$$(1-t)P+tQ = A\cdot R_1+A\cdot R_2$$

...where $R_i$ is a linearly modification of $X$, but this train of logic gets me stuck. However, I can alternatively define $R_1 = (1-t)A$ and $R_2 = tA$ to get:

$$(1-t)P+tQ = R_1\cdot X_1+R_2\cdot X_2$$

From here, can we simply say that $0\leq r_i\leq 1$, for $r_1...r_n = R$ which equates this situation with $0\leq t\leq 1$ for vectors $P$ and $Q$ in vector space $S$ (above) and therefore shows that any $X_1$ or $X_2$ ought to result in a point along the line from $P$ to $Q$?

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
H=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:2\,x-3\,y\leq 6\}
$$
Suppose that $\mathbf x=\langle x_1,x_2\rangle,\mathbf y=\langle y_1,y_2\rangle\in H$ and that $0\leq t\leq 1$. Then
$$
(1-t)\mathbf x+t\mathbf y=\langle(1-t)x_1+ty_1,(1-t)x_2+ty_2\rangle
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
2\,\{(1-t)x_1+ty_1\}-3\,\{(1-t)x_2+ty_2\}
&= (1-t)(2\,x_1-3\,x_2)+t(2\,y_1-3\,y_2) \\
&\leq (1-t)\cdot6+t\cdot6 \\
&=6
\end{align*}
Hence $H$ is convex.

Answer (score 2):

If a function $f$ is convex, then for any $\alpha$, the set
$L = \{ x | f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is convex.

To see this, suppose $x_1,x_2 \in L$, $t \in [0,1]$, then
$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le t f(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) \le t \alpha + (1-t)\alpha = \alpha$,
hence $tx_1+(1-t)x_2 \in L$.

The function $f(x) = 2x_1-3x_2$ is linear, hence convex, and 
hence $S = \{ x | f(x) \le  6 \} $ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what $X_1$ and $X_2$ are, but if
$$
2x_1 -3y_1 \leq 6 \text{ and } 2x_2 - 3y_2 \leq 6
$$
Then if $0\leq t\leq 1$ and $x_3 := tx_1 + (1-t)x_2$ and $y_3 := ty_1 + (1-t)y_2$, you need to prove that
$$
2x_3 - 3y_3 \leq 6
$$
Does this help?